# exam class: define new environment which depends on \printanswers

Tags: environments, conditionals, exam

I am having trouble defining a new environment which depends on the \printanswers option of the exam class.

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{framed}

\printanswers
%\noprintanswers 

\newenvironment{note}{\ifprintanswers\begin{framed}\noindent\textbf{Note:}\par\noindent}{\end{framed}\fi}

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
question
\begin{solution}
    this is the solution
\end{solution}

\begin{note}
    this is a note
\end{note}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```

When I use \printanswers everything looks fine, but when I use \noprintanswers  I get the error:

```
! Incomplete \iffalse; all text was ignored after line 17.
```

I want the notes environment to be hidden when I use \noprintanswers.

Comment: If the answer below fits your request consider to accept and upvote it in order to show your appreciation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To suppress an environment, one technique is to make it equal to the `{comment}` environment defined by the verbatim package. Another is to put the body of the command into a `\vbox` and throw away the `\vbox`, which is the solution the exam environment uses. Here's the `\vbox` approach:

```
\documentclass{exam}
\usepackage{framed}

\newenvironment{note}{%
    \ifprintanswers
        \begin{framed}\noindent\textbf{Note:}\par\noindent
    \else
        \setbox0\vbox\bgroup
    \fi
}{%
    \ifprintanswers
        \end{framed}%
    \else
        \egroup
    \fi%
}

\printanswers
%\noprintanswers

\begin{document}
\begin{questions}
\question
question
\begin{solution}
    this is the solution
\end{solution}

\begin{note}
    this is a note
\end{note}

\end{questions}
\end{document}
```